# API accepts URL but won't accept URL in a variable

Tags: json, ajax, api

I want to be able to dynamically generate my API queries using location.

if I console.log out my geolocation and copy that to my ajax API URL it works as it should.

However, the moment I try to pass the URL a variable with the string in it, it stops working.

So when I remove the ajax URL and replace it with the geoAddress variable, which contains the same URL, it stops working.

Here's the codepen http://codepen.io/Middi/pen/peLMBQ

Here's my code.

```
var geoAddress;

$(document).ready(function ($) {

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

        geoAddress = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + position.coords.latitude + "&lon=" + position.coords.longitude + "&units=metric&appid=6776250c9f90718881dbecfc4c7c5319";

    });
}


$.ajax({
    url: geoAddress,
    success: function (parsed_json) {
        var location = parsed_json.name;
        var country = parsed_json.sys.country;
        var temp_c = Math.round(parsed_json.main.temp);
        var description = parsed_json.weather[0].description;
        var icon = parsed_json.weather[0].icon;


        // Add to Dom
        $('.weather-place').html(icon + "<p>" + location + ", " + country + "</p><p>" + temp_c + "°C</p>" + "</p><p>" + description).fadeIn(400);

    }
});
});
```

Comment: So when I remove the ajax url and replace it with geoAddress variable, which contains the same URL, it stops working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error arrive in your code because AJAX call instantly fire without waiting for over IF condition. That's why when Ajax call fire it's receive blank value in variable `geoAddress`

**Try this way it's work :**

```
var geoAddress;

$(document).ready(function ($) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

            geoAddress = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + position.coords.latitude + "&lon=" + position.coords.longitude + "&units=metric&appid=6776250c9f90718881dbecfc4c7c5319";

            $.ajax({
                url: geoAddress,
                success: function (parsed_json) {

                    var location = parsed_json.name;
                    var country = parsed_json.sys.country;
                    var temp_c = Math.round(parsed_json.main.temp);
                    var description = parsed_json.weather[0].description;
                    var icon = parsed_json.weather[0].icon;

                    // Add to Dom
                    $('.weather-place').html(icon + "<p>" + location + ", " + country + "</p><p>" + temp_c + "°C</p>" + "</p><p>" + description).fadeIn(400);
                }
            });

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome brother :)